# How to use bash to replace a string

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to comment out this line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 test test
```

to become:

```
#127.0.0.1 test test
```

How to a one liner in bash command line to do this to find the line that just starts with 127?  I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sed(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed -i '/^127/s/^/#/' /etc/hosts
```

`-i` means to do the substitution in place, so the substitution happens in `/etc/hosts`, not on stdout which is standard.

in `'/^127/s/^/#/'`, `'/^127/'` means find a line starting with 127 (`^` is the start of line anchor), the `s/^/#/` substitute the start of that line with a `#`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with the following command:

```
sed -i 's/127.0.0.1 test test/#127.0.0.1 test test/g' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -i.bak 's/^127/#&/' /etc/hosts
```

`-i.bak` - in place replace and create backup file with *.bak*